# Jquery - how do you search for an element using an attribute value you set using .data

Tags: jquery

Im setting index numbers on a html lists item $("li").data("index", someValue).

I don't know how to find a specific li based on this index value. Ive searched on here and Ive seen a few posts re: html5 data attributes but Im using JQuerys .data function to append data to the dom and not to the html itself.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
 $('selector').filter( function() { return $.data(this,'foo') == 'desired'; } )
              ...
```

Comment: On a side note to this, you should use $.data(element, key).  I couldn't find the test for fetching (I assume it is similar), but setting is up to 10x faster than using $().data(). Test example:
http://jsperf.com/jquery-data-vs-jqueryselection-data

Comment: @Greg - that makes sense since I already have the element.  If I were invoking it on the selector (instead of in the filter), I probably wouldn't bother as the code would be more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I usually set an id to the li that help retrieve it easily (if I understood your problem). Something like :

```
<ul>
   <li id="my-list-id-1">...</li>
   <li id="my-list-id-2">...</li>
   <li id="my-list-id-3">...</li>
   <li id="my-list-id-4">...</li>
</ul>
```

And then, to find the specific li, it's just as easy as :

```
$('li#my-list-id-' + index)
```

Hope this helps.